# Verify id on connection nodejs

Tags: node.js

Im trying to verify the id of the client so it doesnt get duplicate because I will need it to send direct messages to other clients.

The connected clients are saved at Array conexoes and I only generate the id when the client connects

```
var broadcast = function (msg,origem){
  conexoes.forEach(function(con){
        if(con === origem) return;
        con.write(msg);
  });
};

net.createServer(function(con){
    conexoes.push(con); // add client
    con.id = Math.floor(Math.random()*50); // generate id for client
    con.write("Servidor ativo.\n");
    con.on('data', function (msg) {
        var comando = msg.toString();
        console.log("cmd-> " + comando);
        if(comando.indexOf('#name') === 0) {
            var nome = comando.replace('#name','');
            broadcast(con.nome+' é '+nome);
            con.nome = nome;
            return;
        };
        
        console.log('id->' + con.id);
        console.log('con-> '+con.nome);
        broadcast(con.nome + ' -> ' + msg,con);
    });

    con.on('end',function () {
        broadcast(con.nome + ' saiu', con);
        // splice(remover coneção pos, qt)
        conexoes.splice(conexoes.indexOf(con), 1); 
    })

    con.on('error', (e) => {
        if (e.code == 'ECONNRESET') { 
            // console.log(e) :
            // errno: -4077,
            // code: 'ECONNRESET',
            // syscall: 'read'
            console.log("Um cliente se desconectou");
        }else{
            console.log(e.toString());
        }
    });
}).listen(1213);
```